# search on vs2010 skips regions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

when searching within VS 2010 it does not search within regions sometimes. (is a C# code)

Any on else having this problem any comments are welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "Search hidden text" checkbox has indeed been removed from VS2010.  However, VS should be searching within collapsed regions by default now, so I don't understand why you're having problems.

The removal of the option to *not* search hidden text in the Find dialog has been filed as a [bug over at Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552975/no-more-search-hidden-text-in-find-and-replace-dialog).

Microsoft responded:

> ... We intentionally removed the "Search hidden text" checkbox from
>   the Find and Replace dialog and changed Find's behavior to always
>   search hidden text. ...

Microsoft invited justification for the reinstatement of the feature and there are a number of posts explaining why it's useful (posts I agree with), but the issue is currently statused as 'Closed as By Design.'  Microsoft did say they'll add the feature to the list of suggestions though not necessarily as an option in the Find dialog.

Confusingly enough, [MSDN help on Quick Find, Find and Replace Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87a13zt0.aspx) describes the checkbox and its behavior as if it's still there (and a Community Content comment correctly notes the feature isn't present).

Comment: thanks Jay.
in VS 2010 I dont find the Search hidden text. I read that they removed the checkbox for it and the normal behaviour should search hidden text.

Comment: @ramnz My apologies - when I answered the question I was too lazy to actually fire up VS2010.  When I did (prompted by your comment above) I found you were right.  I rewrote my answer.

Comment: thanks Jay. would like to say that part of what I experiencing is sometimes it does not seach regions in C# code. Any one else having this issue.